# how to remove nav item on window resize?

Tags: javascript

[image: I want target to prepent in more dropdown when screen size is below 1190px & remove target from dropdown when screen size is above 1190px]

[image: This is the outcome i want]

I can make target disappear easily but target to appear in dropdown part is tricky. I've used window.onresize & window.onload with below condition

`if (window.innerWidth < 1190 && window.innerWidth > 1188) {           var dt = document.createElement("dt");           dt.innerHTML = 'Target';           dt.className = '.target'           dl.prepend(dt);         }         if (window.innerWidth > 1189 && window.innerWidth < 1191) {           console.log('done')           dt?.remove()         }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using CSS for this, then a really easy way to do it would be to use media queries.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1189px) and (max-width: 1191px) {
  .target {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This part is already done, I need to move target from nav to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create static targets and manage who is gonna be hidden using classes:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqjkLm5d/85/)

```
  <nav>
    <ul>     
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        Item
      </li>
      <li id="target-main">Target</li>
      <li class="nav-more-container">More
        <ul class="nav-more-list">
         <li id="target-more">Target</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
 const {
  innerWidth
 } = window;

 const targetMain = document.getElementById("target-main");
 const targetMore = document.getElementById("target-more");

 if (innerWidth < 1190) {
   targetMain.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
   targetMore.setAttribute("class", "");
 } else {
   targetMain.setAttribute("class", "");
   targetMore.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
 }
})
```